# Can a Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard share the same Nano Transceiver?

Tags: usb, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I have a notebook which I have plugged a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 3500 into.  I like it because it has a Nano Transceiver so I can leave it in the notebook, and it has a power on/off switch.

I'd like to get a wireless keyboard to work with it but they have a much larger USB transceiver.  Can I use one of these keyboards with the existing Nano Transceiver?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Microsoft peripherals do not seem to support this usage. You might want to look in to upgrading to Logitech Unifying devices, which use a universal micro receiver. Logitech tends to be on the pricey end, but I'm not aware of anything at a lower price point with proper universal receiver functionality. You could just look in to buying a Microsoft keyboard and mouse as a set, since they'd come together with one receiver for both.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like no, the MS peripherals don't work that way, but something else you can look into is bluetooth-- you can find micro bluetooth receivers (if there's not already one built into your laptop), and it should work with any bluetooth mouse or keyboard-- or both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Nano, but it looks like the [Microsoft Wireless Desktops](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-desktop-800/2LF-00001) uses one dongle for both keyboard and mouse.

[image: Microsoft Wireless Desktop 800]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going for a Logitech combo which I'm pleased with.  I can hook up to 6 different devices onto the same Nano Transceiver.

It's a shame Microsoft can't do something similar. The range of Bluetooth devices (which I did consider) was unsuitable.

I'm using the Wireless Mouse 3500 on another system now.